# getting dropdownlist value with el

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, el

I have now been looking like 5 hours for a solution and it should be simpel but i just dont get it.

I got a dropdown list filled with values from my database and now i want to get the selectet item of this dropdown list and set it to a java variable using EL.

Edit : The dropdown list works fine. What i need is to get the current selectet value and save it into a java variable

here is my attempt  with the  tag but it wont work

```
 <select id="dep" name="dep">
                        <c:forEach items="#{departmentBean.depList}" var="item">  
                            <c:set var="#{courseOfStudiesBean.depName}" value="#{item.name}" />
                            <option value="#{item.name}" >#{item.name}</option>  
                        </c:forEach> 
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="dep" value="#{courseOfStudiesBean.depName}">
                 <f:selectItems value="${courseOfStudiesBean.departmentValues}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$` (immediate evaluation) instead of `#` (deferred evaluation).

```
<select id="dep" name="dep">
  <c:forEach items="${departmentBean.depList}" var="item">  
      <option value="${item.name}" >${item.name}</option>  
  </c:forEach> 
</select>
```

You may receive form submit data in JSP via `${param}` collection.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.dep}">
  <c:out value="${param.dep}"/>
  <c:set var="selection" value="${param.dep}" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: The dropdown list works fine. What i need is to get the current selectet value and save it into a java variable.

But i will try this

Comment: @user1517683 - Use `${param.dep}` when you submit the `<form>`